# App Service does not load web-app after successful deployment from Azure DevOps release pipeline

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-web-app-service

I created a release pipeline in Azure DevOps. Created an ARM service connection to connect with the Azure App service that I created to host my web-app. The release was successful and it showed that the deployment finished. But when I entered the app-service url, my web-app did not load.
Any reason why? Thanks!

Comment: What type of application? Website or Web API? If WebAPI, you need to hit the exact endpoint.

Comment: Hi Prawin! Its a website

Comment: Are you hitting the root? or any specific page? Can you try to access a specific page like https://example.azurewebsites.net/default.html

Comment: Its a basic Angular app. I want my app service to host it on successful deployment

Comment: what is the url that you are accessing?

Comment: The app service url  - https://<app-service-name>.azurewebsites.net

Comment: Got it. Can you access a specific page that is available in your Angular app some like https://<app-service-name>.azurewebsites.net/default.html? and also check Console & Network tab in the developer tools to see if there is any error?

Comment: This is what I get.  _DevTools failed to load SourceMap: Could not load content for https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/bootstrap/4.1.1/bootstrap.min.js.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE_FAILURE_

Comment: Yes. So fix it :-)

Comment: @Prawin can you elaborate?

Comment: the bootstrap.min.js.map file is not available. you need to find the appropriate url which is valid

Answer (score 0):

> DevTools failed to load SourceMap: Could not load content for ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/bootstrap/4.1.1/bootstrap.min.js.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE_FAILURE

From the error message, it seems that this issue is related with Browser Extension.

There is a known issue in Chrome recently.

Here is [a github ticket](https://github.com/dequelabs/axe-core/issues/1977) about the Chrome extension issue.

If you are using chrome  Browser, you could check if the have installed the extensions mentioned in the ticket(e.g. LastPass , AdBlock).

You could try to disable them and check if it could work.

Or you could also try to use other browsers(e.g. firefox) to visit the website: `example.azurewebsites.net/default.html`

On the other hand, you could enable the following options in `Chrome Browser F12 -> Settings`.

[image]